# Extract operator '['- POSIXlt unclassed list prints datetime

Tags: r, rstudio

**Aim**: To print the first element of the list obtained from POSIXlt object.

**Code**:

```
> x <- as.POSIXlt(Sys.time())
> x
[1] "2016-06-18 23:51:14 IST"
> x[1]
[1] "2016-06-18 23:51:14 IST"
> x[[1]]
[1] 14.70887
> temp <- list(999,23,3)  
> temp[1]
[[1]]
[1] 999
> temp[[1]]
[1] 999
```

When we access the POSIXlt object x using single extract, the entire date-time is printed, but when we similarly access another list (temp), the first element is printed, as a list (as single bracket extract returns the same object). The first element although is retrieved when I use a double bracket extract.New to R, so can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: The problem here is that `x` is a single element list, and `[` stands for subset of the list. So `x[1]` is essentially the same object as `x`, which can be verified if you check `identical(x, x[1])` which returns `TRUE`. So you will have to use `x[[1]]` to extract the first element. That also breaks the analogy you make between `x` and `temp` since `length(x) == 1` while `length(temp) == 3`.

Comment: @Psidom if you are saying it is a one element list, then to acces the first element of that list, wouldn't we have to use `x[[1]][[1]]`, as the first element itself is a list? And when we unclass x, we are returned all the elements of that list, not the single element (the list) of the main list?

Comment: OK. This is indeed a little bit more tricky than I thought. Just made a more detailed answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unusual behavior of indexing a POSIXlt object from normal list is related to how the `[` operator is defined for `POSIXlt` class. If you look at the source code of `[.POSIXlt`, you will find that it is defined in a quite contra intuitive way. Instead of subsetting the list, it is looping through the list, pick up each element and reassign the attribute back which makes `x[1]` essentially the same as `x`. So my comment has been misled by the `length(l)` which returns one, which is because `length` function for class `POSIXlt` is defined in such a way. Check the two function definition more carefully, and you will see why the behavior is not as normal `list`:

`[` function definition for `POSIXlt`:

```
`[.POSIXlt`
function (x, ..., drop = TRUE) 
{
    val <- lapply(X = x, FUN = "[", ..., drop = drop)   
    # note how the above line has looped through the original list and collected all of them
    attributes(val) <- attributes(x)
    val
}
<bytecode: 0x105dc90d8>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

`length` function definition for `POSIXlt`:

```
length.POSIXlt
function (x) 
length(x[[1L]])     # this will always return one
<bytecode: 0x102270a68>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

And also since `[[` is not defined for `POSIXlt` class, it will still behave as a normal list will do.

Comment: In the `[.POSIXlt`, why not simply return `x`? When essentially both `x[1]` and `x` are the same.

Comment: @AdityaAgrawal I'll wait for senior `R` user to answer your question. But also notice that the function allows you to pass the parameter `drop`.

Comment: I would guess that is meant for the `[` to drop the dimensions of an array or matrix, but I am not sure how that works here.